# Would quantum superposition stop if we observe the particle in the case of photosynthesis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction-collapse, biology, quantum-measurements

I started looking up more into quantum biology from photosynthesis to genetics mutation and how they are explained by quantum properties. my question is about the case of photosynthesis: quantum superposition offers a valid explanation as to why photosynthesis is highly efficient at converting sunlight into energy since the exciton ( the traveling electron-and-hole where it once was) can take all the possible paths to the reaction center at the same time. My question is:  what would happen if we observe the particle's movements? Would it take one path and thus disturb the entire chemical process?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For my best knowledge, there is no scientific consensus on quantum effects in photosynthesis. The recent experiments (as I remember, the most recent is about 2018) hint that quantum effects occur, but debates are continuing. Could you please provide more details, especially references which you follow?

Comment: I don't think you need quantum theory for that. A classical vibration analysis would probably yield similar system behavior. Whatever you want to think about it, please try to stay away from the particle picture. There are no particles in play here. This is a molecule absorbing a quantum of energy from the electromagnetic field. Nobody is "observing" this process and it can not be observed in the way you think. There is no detector system that works below the scale of atoms. That's just a really poor extrapolation of misunderstood theory.

Answer (score 0):

Any process that copies information out of a quantum system can suppress interference: this effect is usually called decoherence

https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245

There are models of photosynthesis with interference and models without interference

https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06528

If the models with interference are true then interactions that copy information out of the system, such as measurements, might make it less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a general question on Feynman's infinite possible path when a quantum particle is traveling from one point to other point. It's like single particle interference experiment where we can explain the interference using this infinite paths explanation (single particle at a time in a double slit experiment). But if you starts observing the particle's path using a detector then the interference pattern would disappear and you would get only the classical result.